# Missing layout inspector left and right detail pane of Android Studio 2.2 preview 2/3/4/5

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I upgraded Android Studio 2.2 preview 2 recently but somehow the left and right detail pane (circled below) of layout inspector is missing. How can I make them appear again? Is it a bug of Android Studio?

[image]

The tool windows snaphot when I open an `.li` file:

[image]

**Updates 20160609:**

Android Studio 2.2 preview 3 still got this problem.

**Updates 20160705:**

Android Studio 2.2 preview 4 still got this problem.

**Updates 20160715:**

Android Studio 2.2 preview 5 still got this problem. As reported by a member below.

Comment: FYI, I just updated to 2.2 preview 3 and the problem is still here.

Comment: I just had same issue, a minute ago they were there, now, they are not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bug is already [tracked officially](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210440).

**EDIT (I don't actually believe this, but that's the way it is)**

The bug is fixed in Preview 5. The reason why you still don't see the additional panels is because **they are shrunken to size 0**. Check the following demo video: https://vid.me/ZRKv

Thanks [Mattia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2837959/mattia-maestrini) and [Mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821173/mario-lenci)

> [...] Unfortunately, this won't be in until 2.2 Preview 4.

Comment: I don't understand how they could be so dumb?

Comment: according to the bugtracker "Will be fixed in 2.4 canary."